# Navigo router - implementing detour login

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, router

Here's the use case I'm trying to implement using Navigo router:

When a user visits the URL, if the user is not logged in, I need to navigate to login page. Once logged in, need to go to the page the user was originally interested in.

This is pretty much the standard in most applications. Just seeing if I can implement in Navigo.

A small (almost working) prototype:

```js
  const router = new Navigo('/', {hash: true});
  const app = document.getElementById('app');

  let loggedIn = false;

  router.on('/login', function(){
    console.log('**** in login');
    app.innerHTML = `
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type=button value="Click to login" onclick="loggedIn=true; alert('you are now logged in!'); router.navigate('/home')"></input>
    `
  });

  router.hooks({
    before(done, match){
      console.log('check if logged in');
      if(loggedIn){
        done()
      } else {
        console.log('need to login');
        done(false);
        //console.log(router)
        router.navigate('/login');
      }
    }
  });

  router.on('/home', ()=>{
    console.log('in home');
    app.innerText = "In home"
  });

  router.on('/about', function(){
    console.log('in about');
    app.innerText = "In about"
  });

  router.on('/', function(){
    console.log('in /');
    // app.innerText = "In /"
    router.navigate('/home')
  });

  router.navigate('/');
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/navigo"></script>
```

Currently after login, the user is taken to the '/home' page, as that is hardcoded.

```js
alert('you are now logged in!'); router.navigate('/home')
```

Is it possible to configure this so the user is taken the page originally interested in (for e.g. /about)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to pass the route you want to navigate to, after a successful login, to the login route handler.
You can do this by changing your before-hook like this:

```
    before(done, match){
      if(loggedIn){
        done()
      } else {
        console.log('need to login');
        const routeToGoto = router.getCurrentLocation().hashString.substring(1) || "home"
        console.log(routeToGoto)
        done(false);
        router.navigate('/login?goto_here=' + routeToGoto);
      }
    }
  });
```

The very first time you hit the page, resolve has not yet been called, which is why I get the route using `getCurrentLocation`.

Now, in your login-handler, check whether the URL includes a query-parameter with the route to go to, if not, just set it to goto "home"

```
router.on('/login', function(match){
    console.log('**** in login');
    const routeToGoto = match?.params?.goto_here || "home";
    app.innerHTML = `
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input id="login-btn" type=button value="Click to login"</input>`

    document.getElementById('login-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){  
      loggedIn = true;
      console.log("logged in")
      router.navigate('/'+routeToGoto);
    })
   });
```

This should solve your problem